Flutter Range Error: value not in range: -16
when I was using Flutter's encrypt: ^5.0.3 dependence to encrypt and decrypt string data, I encountered the occasional unsolvable RangeError in release mode:
RangeError: Value not in range: -16

Here is my code:
import 'package:encrypt/encrypt.dart' as encrypt;

class EncryptedStorage {
  
  static final key = encrypt.Key.fromUtf8(randomString32);

  static final iv = encrypt.IV.fromUtf8(randomString16);

  static final encrypt.Encrypter encryptor = encrypt.Encrypter(
    encrypt.AES(
      key,
      mode: encrypt.AESMode.cbc, 
      padding: "PKCS7", 
    ),
  );

  static String getEncryptedString(String originalString) {
    final encrypt.Encrypted encrypted = encryptor.encrypt(originalString, iv: iv);
    return encrypted.base64; 
  }

  static String getStringByEncryptData(String encryptedData) {
    final String decrypted = encryptor.decrypt64(encryptedData, iv: iv);
    return decrypted;
  }
}

I've gotten this RangeError while I calling getOriginalStringByEncryptData(). And it's always the value -16.
Does anyone know the cause of the error?
This error appears on some iPhone devices. It's occasional. I don't know how to reproduce this error.
Here is the detail of flutter doctor
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.22.1, on macOS 14.5 23F79 darwin-x64, locale en-GB)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.4)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2023.3)
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2022.2.4)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2022.2.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.89.1)


Both the encryption and decryption errors are more likely to be due to bugs in the encrypt package or in the underlying PointyCastle library. An empty plaintext encrypted with AES/CBC/PKCS#7 results in a ciphertext of 1 block (16 bytes). Consequently, there should be no empty ciphertext. But even if an empty ciphertext is passed for decryption, libraries usually tolerate this and return an empty plaintext.

Mostly it occurs when you try to Encrypt and Decrypt the Empty String.
If you want to reproduce is try passing Empty String and Encrypt/Decrypt it.
To avoid this you can check whether String is isNotEmpty and then Encrypt/Decrypt it
if (originalString.isNotEmpty) {
// Encrypt/Decrypt Here
} else {
//Do nothing
}


Thanks so much! I successfully reproduced the issue. The reason is that the data to decode is an empty string.

The number of characters for the original string must be greater than or equal to 16

Thanks, I found out that the reason is that the data to decode is an empty string.
